# Evaluating this triple integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Not sure if I've made a mistake with this, because I get $5/e -5/3$ but the answer says $1/e$.

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 ye^{-xy} \ dx \ dy \ dz$$

http://bit.ly/1fHfZhr

Comment: I've edited your post to fix the broken MathJax; please make sure it's correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to render like the picture I posted...

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You can't do exponents like that.

Comment: @T.Bongers And... now he's edited your editing to break the MathJax; rinse wash repeat ;)

Comment: Haha I think we both edited it at the same time. I didn't touch anything you've done.

Comment: What is the expression inside the expoential??

Comment: Assuming we have now got the integral you wanted, the answer is $1/e$.  As you haven't posted your working I can't say what you did wrong.

Comment: The whole things is the triple integral, each one from 0 to 1, of the expression (y * e to the power of ( -x * y ))

Comment: @JamesAdams I've edited it, please see if it's correct

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. :)

Comment: I guess the easiest path would be first integrate $z$, then $x$ and then $y$.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment last one, because i don't have rep.

There is a mistake : $\left[ -e^{-xy} \right]^1_0 = -e^{-y} - (-e^0) = 1-e^{-y}$

Correctly done here :

$$\int\limits^1_0\int\limits^1_0\int\limits^1_0 {y e^{−xy}}\,dx dy dz = \int\limits^1_0\int\limits^1_0 {[−e^{−xy}]}^1_0\,dy dz = $$

$$= \int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1 1-e^{-y}\,dydz = \int\limits_0^1 (y + e^{-y})|^1_0\,dz =$$

$$=  \int\limits_0^1 (1 + e^{-y} -1)\,dz = \int\limits_0^1 e^{-1}\,dz = e^{-1}z|^1_0 = e^{-1} = {1\over e}$$

Comment: Very true, and very embarrassing! I leave your answer as the correct one, perhaps I'll suggest a few edits to your MathJax however.

Comment: I try to follow this guide here : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference